# How to pass a variable in document.getElementById. As well as getting undefined when calling a value in an array

Tags: javascript, html

```
    <iframe id="frmFile" src="Book1.txt" onload="generateInventory();" style="display: none;"></iframe>

    <script>
    function csvpls() {
    var oFrame = document.getElementById("frmFile");
    var strRawContents = oFrame.contentWindow.document.body.childNodes[0].innerHTML;

    while (strRawContents.indexOf("\r") >= 0)
    strRawContents = strRawContents.replace("\r", "");
    var arrLines = strRawContents.split(",");
    return arrLines
    }

    function generateInventory(a, b) {
    var xx = csvpls()
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.style.width = "1000px";
    div.style.height = "100px";
    div.style.background = "red";
    div.style.color = "white";
    div.innerHTML = "Hello " + xx[a] + " yes!";

    document.getElementById(b).appendChild(div);
    }

    </script>

    <div id="Q1"></div>
    <script>
    generateInventory(20, Q1);</script> 
</body>
```

I am trying to create edit multiple divs with the following code. I hope to call each function with parameters to create the divs and put content in them.
So I have some problems with the code above. First off, document.getElementById(str).appendChild(div); is not working the way I want it to. It works if I put the div id "Q1" instead of b. Just wondering, if I can pass a variable through it. Secondly, when I change the div to "Q1", the div is generated, but the content in there is "Hello undefined Yes". If I call the array with xx[20] instead of xx[a], I would get what I want which is "Hello content yes". Sorry, this probably seems like a nuisance, any help is appreciated.

Comment: "Just wondering, if I can pass a variable through it" --> Yes, the arguments to [getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) are just a string representation of the ID, you can pass that through as many functions as you want. Have you tried console logging the values of `b` and `xx`?

Comment: You're not passing the string `"Q1"` to `generateInventory(20, Q1)`, you're passing an undefined global variable called `Q1`.

Comment: `generateInventory(20, 'Q1')` second argument of this function needs to be a string and valid attribute 'id' of HTML element.

Comment: Can you guys explain how to pass it as a string then? I tried 'Q1', "Q1", .toString(); and I am getting no luck.